# How can I filldraw this rose in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I was trying to filldraw this rose with five petals using tikz, but I didn't succeed.

```
r=(\sqrt{\frac{7}{\pi}})*cos {5*\theta}), \theta \in [0,2\pi]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you are! (also see [this 5-petal water lily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573615/140722))

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\R{sqrt(7/pi)}   
\draw[smooth,magenta,fill=violet!30] plot[domain=0:36*5,samples=200] (\x:{\R*cos(5*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

For fun, the code is rather short with `pstricks` (I replaced the coefficient with a numeric approximation):

```
\documentclass[svgnames, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{arrowinset=0.12,unit=2,plotpoints = 2000, plotstyle=curve, linejoin=1}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\psplot[algebraic, polarplot, linecolor=IndianRed, linewidth=1.2pt, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=MistyRose!50]{-3.1416}{3.1416}{1.5*cos(5*x)}
\psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue, xAxis=true,yAxis=true,labels=none, ticksize=2pt -2pt, showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(-1.8,-1.8)(1.8,1.8)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will it kindly be possible for you to do it with tikz?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know TiKZ well enough to do it. But you can compile it as an independent file (the simplest way is to compile with `xelatex`) and insert the resulting .pdf with `\includegraphics`